# How do I reference the first row in a column that's dynamically referenced by another formula?

Tags: google-sheets, reference

```
Max Max Date    3/17/23 12/8/22 11/28/22
152 ?           96      152     124
124 ?           124     112     103
108 ?           42      76      108
98  ?           11      25      98
108 ?           102     108     90
```

I have the above table. I'm trying to figure out the function needed for the question marked cells. The leftmost column is the highest value in each row. I found out how to find that easily enough with MAX(C2:E2) etc.

What I want to do is: once the max value of the row has been found, to reference the date (the first row) from that column. So for example, 152 was the max value for the second row. I want the "?" in the second row to automatically populate with the date 12/8/22 which is the date that max value was obtained.

I tried to look into HLOOKUP and INDEX functions, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work for what I'm doing. The formula cannot be static, as new dates and values will constantly be added, and new max values/dates needing to be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this for `row 2`

```
=filter(C1:E1,C2:E2=max(C2:E2))
```

OR for arrayformula style you can go with:

```
=byrow(C2:E,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,filter(C1:E1,z=max(z)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your first suggestion worked perfectly. And locking in the first row with C$1:E$1 made it easily duplicatable down the rows. Cheers!

Comment: @DavidLudin If it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it) to treat the thread as solved.